# .then handler being invoked out of order

Tags: http, angular, promise

My ultimate goal is to assign a chunk of database to class based object. To do this I am utilizing promises in typescript with the help of the `.then()` function to chain them. However I am running into brick walls.

```
return(this.httpService.post(someurl, somepayload, someheaders)
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(MyCustomClass.function(MyObject)));
```

However when this code executes the `.then(MyCustomClass.function(MyObject))` before it gets the `response.json()` which is causing issues in my program.

My question is, why are they occurring in that order and is there any way I can force them to execute in sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `MyCustomClass.function(MyObject)`, and passing the returned value to `then()`. What you actually want is to pass a function that, when called, will execute `MyCustomClass.function(MyObject)`:

```
.then(() => {
  MyCustomClass.function(MyObject);
}));
```